# Reverse lookup from Google Spreadsheets key

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I can't figure out where the data in an IMPORTRANGE function is coming from.

How can I use the spreadsheet key to find the the original spreadsheet IMPORTRANGE is pulling from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google spreadsheet URL looks like the following

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mPqoaJW75FlHI_nCIZ-O9MBaTQ5Y58HGf0bdzFMKd-Y/edit
```

Just replace `1mPqoaJW75FlHI_nCIZ-O9MBaTQ5Y58HGf0bdzFMKd-Y` by your own spreadsheet-key.

An alternative is to use

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mPqoaJW75FlHI_nCIZ-O9MBaTQ5Y58HGf0bdzFMKd-Y
```

The same apply, just replace the file id by your spreadsheet-key